# Adicionar uma etiqueta com a quantidade próximo ao campo

Tags: php, html

Quero fazer um botão ou campo de texto, por exemplo, de e-mail, que informe a quantidade de e-mails em cima do texto. Algo como:

> Emails¹³

Isso é feito em PHP ou HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem de usar **HTML** e **CSS** para customizar o modo de apresentação.

O valor a apresentar lá, pode inserir em HTML mas aí seria estático. Supondo que esse valor é dinâmico, ou seja, vai ser alterado, você pode usar **PHP e MySQL** para o pegar de uma base de dados.

Outra alternativa seria usar **JavaScript**.

Comment: a parte estetica eu ja tenho ...entao basicamente ainda teria que criar um bd para armazenar uma string e redirecionar?

Comment: Tudo depende daquilo que você quer mostrar/apresentar. De onde vem em concreto o que voce quer apresentar?

Comment: seria assim tenho um domínio já funcionando e ele registrou um e-mail, desenvolvi um painel de ADM para manuseá-lo e um dos menus eh o acesso ao e-mail, assim queria deixar este numerosinho em cima da palavra incrementando ou decrementando toda vez que chegar ou eu ler um e-mail...